# scala keyword precedence

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, yield

how is "keyword precedence" defined in scala?

Consider this piece of code:

```
for(i <- 1 to 10) yield i
```

This is OK, I get a `Seq` from 1 to 10, but when i try to match right after:

```
for(i <- 1 to 10) yield i match {case x => x.head}
```

There is a compile error: `error: value head is not a member of Int`.

I can surround `for ... yield` in parentheses to give it precedence:

```
{for(i <- 1 to 10) yield i} match {case x => x.head}
```

But I'm still wondering how is the second example code interpreted. I would expect the second example to work properly as well, without surrounding it with parens.

Can anyone explain it to me or point me to the right chapter in specification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second example is interpreted as:

```
for(i <- 1 to 10) yield { i match {case x => x.head} } // won't compile
```

The approximate syntax for *for* is like:

```
for (Enumerators) yield Expr
```

Since `i match { case x => x.head }` parses as a valid expression (token wise), that's how the compiler will see it. So if *Expr* looks like an expression, that's how it will be treated. By that reasoning, the following statements are valid:

```
for(i <- 1 to 10) yield for(j <- 1 to 2) yield (i, j)
for(i <- 1 to 10) yield if (i % 2 == 0) 'a' else 'b'
for(i <- 1 to 10) yield try { 1 / (i - 5) } catch { case _ => }
```

and they are all equivalent to

```
for(i <- 1 to 10) yield { for(j <- 1 to 2) yield (i, j) }
for(i <- 1 to 10) yield { if (i % 2 == 0) 'a' else 'b' }
for(i <- 1 to 10) yield { try { 1 / (i - 5) } catch { case _ => } }
```

Note: the Scala Language Specification is available [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/198) (first link). The relevant section is on page 161 in the Chapter A (Scala Syntax Summary).

Comment: But isn't `i` alone an expression as well? Why does the "i-match" association have higher precedence than "yield-i"? Isn't this inconsistent with other Scala syntax (i.e. left-to-right associativity)?

Comment: Parsers don't look for something that "finishes" the statement, they simply prefer adding to it over closing it. So they'll always take the longest possible thing as "expr".